# How can i fix this error Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

How to fix this error i am using expo react native
ERROR  Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'. this is the errors pls also check my code i have provided
[image]

## My package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "expo": "^46.0.0",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "haversine": "^1.1.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-flexi-radio-button": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-fontawesome": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.8",
    "react-native-progress-circle": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "rn-sliding-up-panel": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

## my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "amdy-edu",
    "slug": "amdy-edu",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

## my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me solve the same issue, Use this instead.

```
npm i git+https://github.com/LarvenLLC/react-native-snap-carousel.git
```

Reference: https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel/pull/929#issuecomment-1221294797

Answer (score 0):

The correct fix here is to switch to `deprecated-react-native-prop-types` or a type system like Typescript.

Comment: In other words, do what the error message is suggesting :p

Comment: @Jaromanda X
 what to do can you tell?

Comment: don't ask me @justforhelp - not my answer - I just pointed out this answer is exactly what the error message is suggesting

Comment: @Jaromanda X
oh i have done that but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in react-native-snap-carousel. You have 2 choices. You either find an alternative or you navigate to node_modules/react-native-snap-carousel and change all imports to deprecated types.